# Kubernetes Ingress for external service being modified to include namespace in the URL

Tags: kubernetes, ingress-nginx

I'm trying to create an Ingress for an external service in an old Kubernetes installation ("v1.16.15"), but for some reason when I apply the manifest, the URL (Host) is modified to include the namespace of the ingress.

My manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: mytest-service
  namespace: test-ns
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: X.X.X.X #External service IP
  ports:
  - name: port443
    port: 9443
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mytest-service
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  ports:
  - name: port443
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: mytest-ingress
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mytest.internalurl.env-N.intranet
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: mytest-service
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
```

Those three objects are created without issues, but when I check the ingress, the URL includes the namespace:

```
kubectl get ingress mytest-ingress -n test-ns
NAME            HOSTS                                      ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
mytest-ingress  mytest.test-ns.internalurl.env-N.intranet  IP1,IP2   80      10m
```

---

Edit: there are multiple ingresses with the Host "internalurl.env-N.intranet" so this could be some sort of conflict avoidance:

```
kubectl get ingress -A | grep ' internalurl.env-N.intranet'
kube-system  kube-system.manager  internalurl.env-N.intranet  IP1,IP2  80  539d
otherNS      usermanagement       internalurl.env-N.intranet  IP1,IP2  80  539d
otherNS      component1           internalurl.env-N.intranet  IP1,IP2  80  539d
otherNS      componentN           internalurl.env-N.intranet  IP1,IP2  80  539d
```

But what I don't understand is that there are other ingresses with subdomains that do not include the namespace. So in the end, my question is what concept am I missing here? Does nginx have some sort of logic to resolve potential host conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

You may try upgrading your Kubernetes cluster to version 1.18 or later.

Newer versions introduced the [`networking.k8s.io/v1`](http://networking.k8s.io/v1) Ingress API group, which offers separate `Ingress` and `ExternalIngress` resources. ExternalIngress lets you specify an external address without including the namespace.

Comment: The long term solution will be the upgrade, but I was wondering what concept I'm missing to not understand the ingress URL change. It seems like this is related to a possible conflict with existing Ingresses, I'll update the question to include more details.